# Failed to read artifact in my case

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am using MacBook. I have installed Apache Maven 3.1.1 .

Under my maven **local** repository path, I see that there is already installed the artifact of my base project:

```
~/.m2/repository/com/my/base/project/MyBase/1.0/MyBase-1.0.jar
```

In another project(feature-project)'s **pom.xml**, I added my base project as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.my.base.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyBase</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

But when I run `maven clean install` under feature-project, I got error:

```
Failed to collect dependencies at com.my.base.project:MyBase:jar:1.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.my.base.project:MyBase:jar:1.0:
```

WhY? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is there a POM file for the artifact - `~/.m2/repository/com/my/base/project/MyBase/1.0/MyBase-1.0.pom`?

Comment: Yes there is. That artifact is installed by 'maven install' command.

Comment: Show the pom file of which you have installed via `mvn install`..